# why R.swift dont creating viewControllers code?

Tags: swift, xcode

this is my code

```
        if let loginViewController = R.storyboard.login.loginViewController()! {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginViewController, animated: true)
        }
```

and i am getting this error:

Value of type '_R.storyboard.login' has no member 'loginViewController'

What could be the problem? i have the script in build phases (based on depencency analisys unchecked)

Comment: Did you set the identifier on that `UIViewController` in `Login.storyboard`?

Comment: you are passing the wrong reference R storyboard.